# Checkout all files from a previous commit with a certain file name

Tags: git

I want to checkout all files with a certain file name.  The path to them looks like this: Assets/stickers/*/icon.png where * is a bunch of different directories (i.e. one of the files is Assets/stickers/a/icon.png another is Assets/stickers/b/icon.png).  How can I write a command that will pull all the files with that name from an old commit?  I tried the following command and didn't get an error, but the files were not checked out:

```
git checkout aa47381b99a38c0cabef28bb54f7a7f119b36797 Assets/stickers/*/icon.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following commands in my repo referring to [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pathspec) but no one worked:

```
git checkout <commit> dir/*/foo.txt
git checkout <commit> dir/**/foo.txt
git checkout <commit> ':(glob)dir/*/foo.txt'
git checkout <commit> ':(glob)dir/**/foo.txt'
git checkout <commit> ':(glob)**/foo.txt'
```

Maybe a bug of pathspec.
As a workaround, this probably works:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r aa47381b99a38c0cabef28bb54f7a7f119b36797 Assets/stickers/ | grep icon.png | xargs git checkout aa47381b99a38c0cabef28bb54f7a7f119b36797
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
git reset --mixed 4702e729f24fc71816835bf9b818ed43f5f5213f Assets/stickers/*/icon.png
```

Comment: @kaitoy this is a soft reset not the hard reset

Comment: @AtulAgrawl `git reset [<treeish>] <paths>` or `git reset [--soft | --mixed | --hard] <commit>` is correct form. Your `git reset [--soft | --mixed | --hard] <treeish> <paths>` is not. And, if <paths> specified `git reset` doesn't checkout anything but updates only index instead.