# Checkout from a commit all files that end with a specific extension

Tags: git

I know how to checkout one file from a commit.

```
git checkout a0b1c3d -- path/to/some/file.txt
```

I also know how to checkout multiple files from a commit.

```
git checkout a0b1c3d -- path/to/some/file.txt path/to/another/file.txt
```

How can we checkout all the files that end with a certain extension? I have tried the following:

```
git checkout a0b1c3d -- *.txt
git checkout a0b1c3d -- */**/*.txt
```

Neither work. Both commands checkout nothing, even though there are *.txt files to checkout from the specified commit.

[Checkout all files from a previous commit with a certain file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242465/checkout-all-files-from-a-previous-commit-with-a-certain-file-name) suggests that there might be a bug in `pathspec`.

Comment: What does the argv for `git` look like in that last case?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand the question, @BrianCain That is, what do you mean by argv?

Comment: I meant what does the actual command line arg list look like from the perspective of `git` itself?  The asterisks shown are globs and sometimes the globs are processed by the shell and sometimes they're processed by the command.  So let's make sure we're solving the right problem.  If you saw a reference that said to use "`*/**/*.txt`" it may be capitalizing on a shell feature that's not present in your shell.

Comment: @BrianCain It looks like this `error: pathspec '*/**/*.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: What version of `git` are you using?

Comment: Git version: `git version 2.10.2.windows.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Quote the glob so your shell passes it along to Git rather than expanding it itself:

```
git checkout -- \*.txt
```

which just worked perfectly for me, it checked out all .txt files (at any level, see git's rules for pathname matching in git help ignore).

Answer (score 0):

Using command substitution it is possible to get all the files with a given extension in your repository. This is possible with `git ls-tree` and `grep`.

The list of the resulting files can be passed to `git checkout`.

You could checkout the `a0b1c3d` version of the files with `txt` extension using the following command:

```bash
git checkout a0b1c3d -- $(git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only -r HEAD | grep .txt)
```